# The argument type 'Stream<MyUser?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<MyUser>?'. Flutter Firebase Problem (App Build)

Tags: firebase, flutter

2 errors in main.dart.
Problem-related to flutter firebase

1. The argument type 'Stream<MyUser?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream?'.
2. The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyUser'.

My main.dart code :

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,     **Error 1**
      initialData: null,             **Error 2**
      child: MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Initaial code**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt8Ex.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following block of code with the below code.

Hopefully, this should fix the issue.

```
    return StreamProvider<MyUser>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,     **Error 1**
      initialData: null,             **Error 2**
      child: MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
```

Replace with the below code:

```
return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().currentUser,     
      initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,             
      child: MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, it Works!

Comment: Great, can you please accept the solution? so that it can help others as well.

Comment: I have a prob, can you review my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324017/could-not-find-the-correct-providermyuser-above-this-wrapper-widget-flutter-f

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68537822/a-value-of-type-streamuser-cant-be-returned-from-the-function-user-becau