# A value of type 'Stream<User?>' can't be returned from the function 'user' because it has a return type of 'Stream<User>?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am getting red line on auth.authStateChanges(),
Error says : **A value of type 'Stream<User?>' can't be returned from the function 'user' because it has a return type of 'Stream?'.**

```
class Auth {
  final FirebaseAuth auth;

  Auth({required this.auth});

  Stream<User>? get user => auth.authStateChanges(); <-- here
```

Update now i get this error:

```
Future<String?> createAccount({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( <-- here **auth**
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password.trim(),
      );
      return "Success";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ```Stream<User?> get user``` changed the nullable on the Stream<User>?

Comment: @RaineDaleHolgado now i am getting error under auth : Undefined name 'auth'. See Update

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth {
  final FirebaseAuth auth;

  Auth({required this.auth});

  Stream<User?> get user => auth.authStateChanges();

  Future<String?> createAccount({required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password.trim(),
      );
      return "Success";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```